# how to open a postgres database created with docker in a database client?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I have a question about how to open a database created with docker using https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter in a database client

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVbG7.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T6dK.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUQj9.png)

COMPOSE LOCAL FILE

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: tienda_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: tienda_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

Comment: How is this related to `django-rest-framework`?

Comment: Can you expand this to say what your actual question is?

Answer (score 0):

Is the port on the container mapped? Try using 127.0.0.1(assuming this is on the same machine) as the host in your local client instead of the container name. If that doesn't work can you share your docker-compose.yaml

Comment: i change host using 127.0.0.1 and say me its error : 
FATAL: there is no «debug» role

Answer (score -1):

You haven't network between containers/services in docker-compose:

You can achieve this in number ways:

1. [link between containers/services](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links). This is a deprecated way but, depends on your docker version still work. Add to your docker-compose file:

```
django:
  ...
  links:
   - postgres
```

2. [Connect services to the same network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks). Add to both your services definition:

```
networks:
     - django
```

Also, you need to [define](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference) network `django` in docker-compose file

```
networks
  django:
```

3. [Connect your services via a host network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#host-or-none). Just add to both services defenition:

```
network: host
```

Comment: Docker Compose [creates a network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), as though you specified `networks: [default]` in these places.  None of what you describe here should be necessary.

Comment: @DavidMaze I know about... But if you, for example, connect to host then the problem will be solved because actually localhost will be accessible to both of services.